# How does C limit a static function's use to only its file?

Tags: c, assembly

I understand that a static function in C allows that particular function to only be call within the confines of that file. What I am interested in is how this occurs. Is it being placed into a specific part of memory or is the compiler applying a specific operation to that function. Can this same process be applied to a function call in assembly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't make it into the object's name table which prevents it from being linked into other stuff.

Answer (score 15):

Declaring a function `static` doesn't really prevent it from being *called* from other translation units.

What `static` does is it prevents the function from being *referred* (*linked*) from other translation units by name. That will eliminate the possibility of *direct* calls to that function, i.e calls "by name". To achieve that, the compiler simply excludes the function name from the table of external names exported from the translation unit. Other than that, there's absolutely nothing special about static functions.

You still can *call* that function from other translation units by other means. For example, if you somehow obtained a pointer to `static` function in other translation unit, you can call it through that pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Functions and other names are exported as *symbols* in the object file. The linker uses these symbols to resolve all sorts of dangling references at link time (e.g. a call to a function defined in another file).  When you declare it `static`, simply it won't be exported as a symbol. Therefore it won't be picked up by any other file. You could still call it from another file if you had a function pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

It's in fact the opposite. When a function is *not* static, its name is written somewhere in the object file, which the linker can then use to link other object files using this function, to the address of that function.

When the function is declared `static`, the compiler simply doesn't put the name there.